# Why post was "bumped to the homepage by Community" without any activity?

Tags: discussion

I am curious - why [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85732/how-to-apply-the-multiple-data-filters-to-dataview-webpart) was "bumped to the homepage by Community" when clearly there is NO activity for more than 4 years?

([screenshoted image](https://www.screencast.com/t/svJubtFTYckD) to capture the moment.. just in case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an automated action based on specific hidden patterns :) so not all automated action is valid from our perspectives because we don't know these hidden patterns.

> **BTW,** there are a lot of automated system flags that raised to specific answers and questions that actually valid! so the community
>   allows us as moderator to check it first to make sure it's valid or
>   not and then take the right action.

What I can say in this case, the Community bumped this question to the homepage because of its **views became > 1000** view.

So the community notes that it's a **Popular Question** that its answer not accepted yet, therefore, it asks us for **reviewing** the provided answers! by trying to do a specific action like

- Upvote the answer if it good and helpful.
- Provide another good answer if it bad.
- Enhance the current answer and question if it needs to some edit!

> One of the community aims is providing a very well answer that satisfies
>   the OP and that would lead to closing the question by accepting the correct answer. Moreover, it will be helpful for all future users.

Hope it makes sense :)

Comment: Thank you. It explains a lot - in this case, the views.

Comment: Good to know. actually there should be a wiki page to list out these kinda info. Really worth to know how we are taking care of our community. cheers.

Comment: IMHO bumped questions only create clutter. There's a pretty big chance OP isn't around any more so the answer won't get accepted. Also, not too many people are keen to answer it. That's just my 2 cents, I might be totally mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of bumping has already been explained on [another answer](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1518/34763): review the existing answers.

For the bumping criteria, the question have to be:

> - Scoring >= 0
> - Not deleted or closed
> - Have gone at least 30 days with no activity
> - Have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that
> - No accepted answer

From [Shog9's answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/241919).